# Want to detect via js if old Flash version is blocked by safari

Tags: javascript, flash, safari

I have a site that uses SWFobject to detect flash.

Unfortunately, now that safari blocks flash unless the user has upgraded to the latest flash, our page can't deliver the non-flash content. Is there a simple way to determine if the user has a functioning version of flash?

I guess I would want to also be able to give the non-flash content to users with various flashblocks (including chrome native flashblock)

I had read about a technique calling a method (e.g. GetVariable("$version")) of the flash from javascript. Would I have to put a timeout to make sure that the flash was instantiated before trying to call the method?

Comment: Hi Tom, did you ever find a solution for this? I'm looking for the same thing.